# finding a way to show image category name in ResNet50 model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, resnet, transfer-learning

I've tried to process a natural image processing to categorize image into three different categories
`[airplane, car, motorcycle]`. which provided below.

```
single_image = load_images('sample_data/')  ## Load airplane image into array of arrays
single_image = resize_images(single_image, inp_img_width,inp_img_height)  ## Resize the image to the predefined size

le.classes_ 
#which shows answer as "array(['airplane', 'car', 'motorbike'], dtype=object)"
```

i use `keras.utils.normalize` to transform image into an array of float in each category

```
single_image_norm = tf.keras.utils.normalize(np.asfarray(single_image))
```

it successfully shows the right category for airplane image when i implement my model.

```
model(single_image_norm)
#which shows answer as "<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 5), dtype=float32, numpy=array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)>"
```

but here, i want to not only shows the array of the category, but also to show the name of the category.
in example for airplane image would be,

```
model(singe_image_norm)
#which answers "airplane"
```

can someone help me? what code should i add/use?
hopefully it can be understand, sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary that maps the index to its corresponding label. Like this:

```
labels_map = {0:'airplane', 1:'car', 2:'motorbike'}
```

You can use `np.argmax` to get the index of the class with maximum probability,

```
idx = np.argmax(prediction, axis=-1)
```

Then you can pass this `idx` to the dictionary and you will get the predicted label text,

```
text = labels_map.get(idx)
```